# Isn't there a flaw in magical security?

Tags: harry-potter

It is told in The Deathly Hallows that elf magic is not like wizard magic

> "Well, it's obvious, isn't it, Harry?" said Ron. "He Disapparated!"
>
> "But ... you couldn't Apparate in and out of that cave," said Harry,
> "otherwise Dumbledore ¨C "
>
> "Elf magic isn't like wizard's magic, is it?" said Ron, "I mean, they
> can Apparate and Disapparate in and out of Hogwarts when we can't."
>
> <sup>*Harry Potter and the Deathly Hallows chapter 10*</sup>

And a house-elf can apparate wizards with him as Dobby apparated with Harry, Ron, Hermione, Luna, Dean, Ollivanders and Griphook despite the anti-apparating security measures.

So isn't there all the chance in the world that death eaters can enter into Hogwarts or MOM or maybe Gringots with side along apparition with an house-elf?

Comment: As per https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/22399/can-house-elves-side-along-apparate-disapparate-to-from-hogwarts?rq=1, it's not known if they can Side-Along people. That, of course, does not rule them carrying something else in, a bomb or cursed item... which very well may be a security hole.